# jQuery Caption displaying on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, image, caption

I have a problem with a caption that I am trying to do. I hope you can help me.

Basically I'm trying to make the `.caption-holder` to slide up over the image. It is already correctly positioned, but I just can't figure out how to make the caption slide up or appear when I'm on the desired image.

This is my jQuery:

```js
//Caption
$(".photo-container").mouseover(function (){
    $(this)

    imgW = $(this).width();
    imgH = $(this).height();

    $(".caption-holder").css({"display":"block"})
    $(".caption-img-overlay").css({"width":imgW, "height":imgH});
    $(".caption").css({"width":imgW, "padding":"12px 18px 3px 18px"});
});
```

CSS:

```css
.photo-container {
    background:rgba(251,171,0,0.1);
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.caption-holder {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.caption-img-overlay {
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(251,176,0,0.2);
}

.caption {
    width:0;
    height:56px;
    padding:0 0;
    color:#a65500;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    text-shadow:rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 1px 1px 2px;
    background:url(../images/bg_image_caption.png);
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<div class='photo-container'>
  <img src='image.jpg' />
  <div class='caption-holder'>
    <div class='caption-img-overlay'>
      <div class='caption'>
        <h4>Pruebas</h4>
        <p>texto prueba</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you could, please help me out to make the caption slide up :)

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Can you put your code in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) and explain better exactly what's happening and what you want to have happen.

Comment: well the caption dosnt show

Comment: $(".photo-container").mouseover(function (){
   $(this).children(".caption-holder", $(this))
   .slideUp();

Comment: trying it like this now, it now shows the caption on all :S

Comment: `slideUp()` will hide the element, not make it visible. `slideDown()` makes it appear. If you really want to slide up to appear, then you'll have to use `.animate`.

Comment: @Joel: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/BFr5Y/). Note I replaced the image with a div just for testing purposes. The caption appears, it doesn't slide, but you code isn't even trying to do that.

Comment: @Joel: So you have multiple `photo-container`? That's a detail you didn't include in your question. To find the `.caption-holder` that is a child of your clicked on `photo-container` you can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".caption-holder").height(0).show().animate({height: imgH});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BFr5Y/1/)

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BFr5Y/2/) with two pictures using `find()` to get the related `.caption-holder`

Comment: mmm, see it works on fiddle i must be doing something else wrong could you have a look at the web its just a project for a master im doing here in madrid.

http://cice.digitalcore.es/febrero/majestic

Comment: Sorry Matt, im having trouble getting the mouseleave to run any sugestion? :)

Comment: @Joel: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BFr5Y/11/). I just did `.hide()`, but you could add an animation if you want.

Comment: work perfect thank you very much :D i hope that i can ask you another question hehe im trying to select all the other images while im selecting one to make them dim out or something like that i would i do that? im trying to do like this: $('.caption-holder').not(this); but that doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gygHg/
use this sample

```
$('.thumbs li').mouseover(function() {      
$(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(500);
});

$('.thumbs li').mouseleave(function() {       
$(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: ive tried this:

` $(".photo-container img").mouseover(function (){
   $(this).find(".caption-holder")
   .slideUp();
   
   imgW = $(this).width();
   imgH = $(this).height();
   
   $(".caption-holder").css({"display":"block"})
   $(".caption-img-overlay").css({"width":imgW, "height":imgH});
   $(".caption").css({"width":imgW, "padding":"12px 18px 3px 18px"});
  }); `

Comment: yeah i forgot to take out $(".caption-holder").css({"display":"block"}) but still wont work without out it im doing something wrong not sure what